# Beautiful Soup HTML parsing anamoly

Tags: html, python-3.x, web-scraping

I am trying to get the text out of certain class in a HTML using beautiful soup. I have successfully got the texts but, there are some anomalies(unrecognisable characters) in it like shown in the image below. How can I solve it with a python code instead of manually deleting these anomalies. 
[image]

Code:

```
    try:
        html =requests.get(url)
    except:
        print("no conection")
    try:
        soup = BS(html.text,'html.parser')
    except:
        print("pasre error")
    print(soup.find('div',{'class':'_3WlLe clearfix'}).get_text())
```

Comment: It's an encoding error. `html.text` is most likely inferring the wrong encoding. What's the url?

Comment: @GordonAitchJay https://timesofindia.com/india/up-takes-battle-over-recovery-hoardings-to-sc/articleshow/74585106.cms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you access `html.text`, Requests tries to determine the character encoding so it can properly decode the raw bytes it received from the server. The `content-type` header that timesofindia sent is `text/html; charset=iso-8859-1`, which is what Requests went with. The character encoding is almost certainly `utf-8`.

You can fix this by either setting the `encoding` of `html` to `utf-8` before accessing `html.text`:

```
    try:
        html =requests.get(url)
        html.encoding = 'utf-8'
    except:
        print("no conection")
    try:
        soup = BS(html.text,'html.parser')
    except:
        print("pasre error")
    print(soup.find('div',{'class':'_3WlLe clearfix'}).get_text())
```

or decode `html.content` as `utf-8`, and pass that into `BS` instead of `html.text`:

```
    try:
        html =requests.get(url)
    except:
        print("no conection")
    try:
        soup = BS(html.content.decode('utf-8'),'html.parser')
    except:
        print("pasre error")
    print(soup.find('div',{'class':'_3WlLe clearfix'}).get_text())
```

I would *highly* recommend you learn about character encoding and Unicode. It is very easy to get tripped up by it. We've all been there.

[Characters, Symbols and the Unicode Miracle - Computerphile](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MijmeoH9LT4) by Tom Scott and Sean Riley

[What every programmer absolutely, positively needs to know about encodings and character sets to work with text](https://kunststube.net/encoding/) by David C. Zentgraf

[The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/) by Joel Spolsky